# How to download images from image_URL and count the number of repetitions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataset

I have a data-set that contains imageid, imageurl. I need to extract all the images using the image urls and zip them into a file with all the images downloaded. And I need to count the repetitions because some image url's are repeated several times. How do I do this in python?

The approach I was thinking was using a for loop here:
image_id should be the file name

edit1: Added the code, how do i combine both the for loops?

```
import urllib

list1 = []

    for key1 in (csv_file['imageid']):
        list1 = str(key1)+".jpg"
        for key in (csv_file['imageurl']):
           urllib.request.urlretrieve(key, list1)
```

edit 2: [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptW4z.png)

Edit3: Error using library

```
unknown url type: '430'
430
2020-03-02 22:08:26 ('430',)
2020-03-02 22:08:26 (ValueError("unknown url type: '430'"), '430')
2020-03-02 22:08:26 ('error url:', {'url': '430', '_concurrency': 1, 
'_startTm': 1583167106.29, '_endTm': 1583167106.292}, None)
```

This is the error I am facing with this library

Comment: first try to write code and come back when you get error message

Comment: it seem you know `urllib` module - so now you have to learn module [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) and dictionary [collection.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count elements

Answer (score 0):

According to the CSV file you gave, here is an example. But I suggest you don't use this library directly, because it is troublesome. You can try using other packaged libraries, such as requests and simplified_scrapy.

```
import csv
import urllib.request
# from simplified_scrapy import req, utils

list1 = []
with open('test.csv') as f:
  f_csv = csv.reader(f)
  list1 = set([row[1] for row in f_csv if row][1:]) 
for url in list1:
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename=url.split('/')[-1])
  # utils.saveResponseAsFile(req.get(url),url.split('/')[-1])
```

Give you an example of using simplified_scrapy to download pictures

```
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, SimplifiedMain, utils
import csv
class ImageSpider(Spider):
  name = 'ImageSpider'
  def __init__(self):
    with open('test.csv')as f:
      f_csv = csv.reader(f)
      self.start_urls = [row[1] for row in f_csv if row][1:]
    Spider.__init__(self,self.name) # The framework will help you eliminate duplicate data

  def afterResponse(self, response, url, error=None, extra=None):
    try:
      # Create file name
      end = url.find('?') if url.find('?')>0 else len(url)
      name = 'data'+url[url.rindex('/',0,end):end]
      # Save img
      utils.saveResponseAsFile(response,name,'image')
      return None 
    except Exception as err:
      print (err)
SimplifiedMain.startThread(ImageSpider()) # Start
```

Here are more examples of SimplifiedDoc Library: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/

Comment: Could you make this more clearer for me? I'm still new to this.

Where would I have to enter the column name to open the URL's?

Where would I have to enter the file name I wish to set??

Comment: Your URL is stored in file test.csv. use index to retrieve the URL(row[1]). Post a part of your CSV file, and I'll give you an example based on it.

Comment: imageid imageurl acne
18 https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg  100

19 https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg  100

20 https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg 100
21 https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg 100

Comment: Added a link for the CSV file on the question.
Basically have to implement a set to keep the csv file or the library that you mentioned.